# Should the Drop Down menu items be localised

Tags: java, localization

I have a swings application with a drop-down menu. It has three drop down item value:
a. Select
b. Region US
c. Region EU

My problem is figure if I need to localise the menu item ( Region US and Region EU ) ?

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) will help you to localize messages.

You provide files with different base name suffixes, based on the country and the specific language.

Then, `ResourceBudle`  will do the job of finding the relevant file.

See an example here :

[Java ResourceBundle Example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/resourcebundle.html)

> Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
>
> ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.MyBundle",
>   locale);

Comment: Well I use a resource bundle to do that.. But my question is different. It is fundamental question that do I even need to localise drop down menu item ?The fundamental question that we must ask in this regards is:
1. What  are the texts that require to be localized ?
a. Only the text and information that assists the user to enter his input and interact with the UI, should be localized.
Hence we localize the “UI labels” ( text box labels, button labels and titles)  and other texts explaining the meaning of the “UI labels”.
The actual user input is never localized.. Am I right in this argument ?

Comment: Well, let's assume that the user obviously understands the default language of your application. Then , even though she doesn't know anything about the target language, the user may be some kind of administrator, setting parameters for a final user. In such a case, no, don't localize menu items, let the texts be in the default language of the application.